# Explanation of "Declaration of full view must appear in private part"

Tags: compiler-errors, ada

I am getting an error that I cannot find any documentation for to explain what needs to be fixed in my code. The code is:

```
   type BinarySearchTreePoint is limited private;
   type Node;
   type BinarySearchTreePoint is access Node;

   type Node is
      record
         Llink, Rlink : BinarySearchTreePoint;
         Ltag, Rtag : Boolean; --True indicates pointer to lower level,
                               -- False a thread.
         Info : Customer;
      end record;
```

The error that I am getting is `declaration of full view must appear in private part`. It is throwing this error pointing to the line `type BinarySearchTreePoint is access Node;`, and I'm not sure what the error message means.

Comment: Put that in the private part of the package. There's no point declaring a private type and then publishing the details about it.

Comment: See also [*§3.10.1 Incomplete Type Declarations*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-10-1.html).

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'm not sure how? `type BinarySearchTreePoint is limited private access Node;`? Something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say `type Foo is private;` (or `limited private`) you’re required to provide a full declaration in the private part; which, of course, means you’ve got to *have* a private part.

The code you show will compile with

```ada
package Foo is
   type BinarySearchTreePoint is limited private;
private
   type Node;
   type BinarySearchTreePoint is access Node;

   type Node is
      record
         Llink, Rlink : BinarySearchTreePoint;
         ...
```

but if you need `Node` to be visible outside the package you’d need to say something like

```ada
package Foo is
   type BinarySearchTreePoint is limited private;
   type Node is private;
   --  stuff to do with getting a Node from a BinarySearchTreePoint??
   function Content (Of_Node : Node) return Customer;
private
   type BinarySearchTreePoint is access Node;

   type Node is
      record
         Llink, Rlink : BinarySearchTreePoint;
         ...
```

Comment: This solution also explains what  `declaration of full view must appear in private part` means. There are two declarations of `BinarySearchTreePoint`. The first one says `is private`, which means that a full type definition will not be given here. Instead, then, the complete type definition is going to be given in a second declaration in the private part of package `Foo`. This is what the second declaration of `BinarySearchTreePoint` does. The full type definition thus comes into view, for any reader, human or compiler, permitted to see the completed definition.